# Broadcom STA + live USB?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I carry a live 16.04 USB drive around to use on various computers, and I am trying to use it on a machine that requires the Broadcom STA driver for the Wi-Fi card.

However, since it's a live USB, rebooting after using Ethernet to install the driver... well I think you can see the problem there :)

**So, how can I load the Broadcom STA driver without rebooting?**

Answer (score 0):

The Broadcom STA driver, also known as *bcmwl-kernel-source*, as well as its dependency *dkms*, resides on the live session. You should be able to go to Software and Updates > Additional Drivers and install it. Although I haven't a Broadcom wireless device and cannot test, I suspect that your wireless will then work immediately.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work... which is the reason I asked the question :)

Comment: Let's try a couple of things. After you install it, does it help to do: `sudo modprobe -r b43` and then: `sudo modprobe -r bcma` and then: `sudo modprobe wl` ? I wonder if all the wrong drivers that are blacklisted by *bcmwl-kernel-source* are already loaded before you install it.

Comment: The first two commands completed fine (no output is good output, right?), but the final command gave the error: `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules ??Secure boot??

Comment: Hrrrmmmmm... so as you know, I absolutely **hate** UEFI, but the computer I'm booting this on said that if I enabled "Legacy Boot", it would be unable to boot Windows 8. So, I just let it do an EFI boot since it was a live USB anyway... sooooooo... what should I do?

Comment: You could try the whole mokutils thing as outlined in the link, but it requires downloading things which you can't do without wireless, I suspect. Moreover, I have seen very few instances where it actually worked! I am unsure if you can switch to Legacy to boot Ubuntu and then *back* to secure boot for Windows 8. Be careful!